# MySQL Query get categories and children

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I'm quite new to interacting with MySQL. I have a database that I can not modify (A existing system) and I have to get the available categories and its children.

If I run the following query with laravel's query builder I get all the categories and children like this:

```
DB::table('tblknowledgebasecats')->get();

// Returns

    Collection {#337 ▼
      #items: array:13 [▼
        0 => {#338 ▼
          +"id": 1
          +"parentid": 0
          +"name": "System"
          +"description": "..."
          +"hidden": ""
          +"catid": 0
          +"language": ""
        }
        1 => {#340 ▼
          +"id": 3
          +"parentid": 0
          +"name": "Help"
          +"description": "Some Description"
          +"hidden": ""
          +"catid": 0
          +"language": ""
        }
        2 => {#341 ▼
          +"id": 4
          +"parentid": 0
          +"name": "Troubleshooting"
          +"description": "..."
          +"hidden": ""
          +"catid": 0
          +"language": ""
        }
        3 => {#342 ▼
         +"id": 5
         +"parentid": 1
         +"name": "Installation"
         +"description": ""
         +"hidden": ""
         +"catid": 0
         +"language": ""
        }
```

As you can see the result with an id of 5 has a parentid of 1, how do I query this so that they are 'linked' together? It is for building a menu. The output has to be something like this for rendeing the menu in the view:

```
- System
    -- Istallation
    -- ...
- Help
    -- ....
-Troubleshooting
- ...
```

Answer (score 1):

I have a quick solution that uses recursion for finding subcategories but it might not be the best in terms of performance because it does fire multiple queries

The laravel way is to create an [Eloquent model](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent) instead of using the DB Facade. In your model class say App\Category add the following:

```
public static function getChildren(App\Category $category) {
return static::where('parentid', $category->id)->get();
}
```

Now in your controller function to display menus, add the following:

```
$parentcategories = App\Category::where('parentid', 0)->get();
return view('displaymenus', ['categories' => $parentcategories]);
```

In your main view, add the following:

```
<!-- View stored in resources/views/displaymenus.blade.php -->
<ul>
@foreach($categories as $category)
<li> {{ $category->name }} @include('displaysubmenus', compact('category')) </li>
@endforeach
</ul>
```

In your sub menu view, add the following:

```
<!-- View stored in resources/views/displaysubmenus.blade.php -->
<ul>
@foreach(App\Category::getChildren($category) as $subcategory)
<li> {{ $subcategory->name }} @include('displaysubmenus', ['category' => $subcategory]) </li>
@endforeach
</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, this works and will do fine for now, is there any other way I can get the results from the database with one query?